# How do I Create an Array of Images Downloaded from AWS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, objective-c-blocks

**Scenario:** I have a game that contains multiple users in the same game. Each user has a turn to score points. When it's their turn I want their image to show up in the imageView.

Each user has an option to add their own image (which gets saved to AWS), but if a user doesn't have an image, they get assigned a default one.

**Problems:** I'm able to successfully create an array of images, but I have two issues:

1. A user with an image stored gets assigned the default image before completing the download block. Once the download completes, then their image changes to their stored image.
2. When a user adds a new image, their image never updates. It shows their previous image that was added, despite AWS only having the updated image.

**Code:**

```
-(void)getUserImagesFromServer {

self.userPlayerImages = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *userId in self.playerUserIds) {

    // Construct the NSURL for the download location.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:userId];
    NSURL *downloadingFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    // Construct the download request.
    AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *downloadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];
    downloadRequest.bucket = @"boxscore-user-pictures";
    downloadRequest.key = userId;
    downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL;

    [self downloadRequest:downloadRequest:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){

            if (self.tempResultCount == 1) {
                [self.userPlayerImages addObject: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
            } else {
                [self.userPlayerImages addObject:self.tempPlayerImage];
            }
        }
    }];
}
}

-(void) downloadRequest:(AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *)downloadRequest :(myCompletion) compblock{

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

__block int taskResult;
// Download the file.
[[transferManager download:downloadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                       withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                                                           if (task.error){

                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
taskResult = 0;

                                                           } else {
                                                               NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded Image!");
taskResult = 1;

                                                           }
                                                           self.tempResultCount = taskResult;

                                                           return nil;
                                                       }];


compblock(YES);
}
```

**UI for visual reference:**

[image: Image1]

**UPDATE:**

Here's the code used to save the image to AWS:

```
-(void)saveImageToServer:(UIImage*)image {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.sud objectForKey:@"userId"]]];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.bucket = @"boxscore-user-pictures";
uploadRequest.key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.sud objectForKey:@"userId"]];
uploadRequest.body = fileUrl;

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

[[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                   withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                                                       if (task.error) {
                                                           if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                                                               switch (task.error.code) {
                                                                   case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                                                                   case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                                                                       break;
                                                                   default:
                                                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                       break;
                                                               }
                                                           } else {
                                                               // Unknown error.
                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                       if (task.result) {
                                                           AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
                                                           // The file uploaded successfully.
                                                       }
                                                       return nil;
                                                   }];

}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but it seems that you have to have a notification mechanism so that  when AWS gets a new image, the app knows to re-download them.

Comment: @johnelemans I call this method every time someone adds a new photo. Do you think attempting to save an image locally causes an issue since it has the same name/file path? These images are named after a user's id, so every new image has the same name.

Comment: ah, show the code where you update the local image.

Comment: @johnelemans I added an update to my question that shows the code used to save/upload the image.

Comment: but you don't put the new image into userPlayerImages?

Comment: @johnelemans Well, I want to upload to AWS only, but then pull down the appropriate images when necessary. So, basically, 1) upload image to AWS, 2) download all the images of the appropriate players and put them in the array. 3) Based on the new array of images, I show the image at the current player's index.